# Using music21j in node js, not in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, music21

I'm attempting to run music21j in node js ( [repo link](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21j#readme) , [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/music21j) ).

I get `ReferenceError: self is not defined`

When trying to simply initialize music21j:

```
const music21 = require('music21j');
const n = new music21.note.Note('F#');
```

Does this mean it's not possible to run outside of the browser, or am I somehow initializing to the wrong environment?

The github documentation states

> ...or use it in your javascript/typescript project

, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the github repo:

> At present it's not possible to run outside of the browser. :-( But we're working on removing certain JQuery patches that should make it easier to do. You may however need to use ES6-style imports.